# How to get to the number split in List

Tags: c#, list

I have one text file where i have a bunch of couples of numbers,which i copy in List.The text file have for example:

```
1 0 30 15 43 23
12 23 10 12 0 1
```

I want to get the exact number of each line ,because i want to compare it with numbers i entered from the console.I tryed `Split(' ')`, but it doesn't work.
I want to compare it the ints so how its that possible too?

```
static void Main()
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt");
    using (reader)
    {
        string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        while(currentLine!=null)
        {
            currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
            Combinations.Add(currentLine);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter six numbers to check the combinations:");
    int a1= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a6 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    FindWinners(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);
}

static void FindWinners(int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4,int a5,int a6)
{
    foreach(var item in Combinations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that calling `item.Split(' ')` in your `FindWinners` method didn't give you an array of the numbers on that line? Is it possible that the separator is the tab character rather than space? You could try `item.Split(' ', '\t')`

Comment: Are you wanting the check if the 6 user inputs are in one of the combinations?

Comment: Yes i want to do that exacly and @JimMischel it doesnt work either ...

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that `item.Split(' ')` isn't working. Can you show us the code you're trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure the issue you're having with splitting the data. As long as you know there are spaces between your combinations of numbers you should be able to use `.Split(' ')`, so check and make sure there is a single space between the numbers in your file.

Then you want to get 6 numbers from the user and see if they match any of the combinations.  For that I would try the following (I'm just using a List that has the data you provided, instead of reading a file):

```
static List<string> combinations = new List<string> {
    "1 0 30 15 100 23",
    "12 23 10 12 0 1"
};

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter six numbers to check the combinations:");
    int a1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int a6 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    FindWinners(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void FindWinners(params int[] numbers)
{
    // Sort the numbers from least to greatest
    Array.Sort(numbers);
    foreach (int[] combo in combinations
        // This select makes the string array
        .Select(combination => combination.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        // This select turns the string array, from the previous select, and turns it into an integer
        //   array sorted from least to greatest.
        .Select(combination => combination.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)).OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(combo.SequenceEqual(numbers) ? "Winner!" : "Loser!");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Enter six numbers to check the combinations:
100
0
30
1
15
23
Winner!
Loser!
```

What's happening in `FindWinners()`:

All the user provided integers are boxed into an integer array by the `params` keyword.  I then `foreach` through each combination, after turning it into an integer array. Both arrays are sorted from least to greatest, then `combo.SequenceEquals(number)` checks that each element, in sequence, are equal to one another.  If they're all equal, I output "Winner!" otherwise I output "Loser!"

Comment: That certainly should work. My only suggestion would be to change your call to `Split` so that it removes empty entries. `c.Split(new[]{' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. That will prevent empty entries if there are multiple spaces between numbers.

Comment: Oh, and you only have to sort the `combo` array once--outside the loop.

Comment: what reference i should add to recognize the select?

Comment: @razi3lbr Add using System.Linq where the other using statements are at the top of your code

Comment: @JimMischel Actually, I think numbers only numbers could probably be sorted above the foreach. combo is created in the foreach and would have to be sorted after each creation.

Comment: @Shar1er80: You're right. The `numbers` array. My bad.

Comment: @razi3lbr That is not part of your question and why does it need to be done with Tasks?